# laravel 5 - css file is not defined in asset manifest?

Tags: laravel, assets, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I get an Error Message with laravel 5, which I don't understand.

```
Next exception 'ErrorException' with message 'File build/css/all.css not             
defined in asset manifest.
```

I haven't installed any asset pipeline or something. Just used elixir to compile, minify and version the scss-file to `all.css` and included it into the master view with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir("css/all.css") }}">`

What is this 'asset manifest' and how to fix this error?`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The question is of course what you want to achieve.

If you simply put `all.css` file into the `public/css` directory and you want to display this file, you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/all.css') }}" />
```

However if you plan to modify this file and you don't want to have caching issues, you can put this `all.css` file again into `public/css` then put into `gulpfile.js`:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version('public/css/all.css');
});
```

Now you'll need to run:

```
gulp
```

in your terminal, and now you can use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/all.css') }}" />
```

as you previously did in your HTML.

It will create `public/build/` folder with `rev-manifest.json` (this file is missing in your case).

I would recommend you to watch [Managing assets Laracasts episode](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/19) to understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue here!! I solve it by creating production version of css. I update gulefile.js as bellow,

```
 elixir(function(mix) {
     mix.sass('app.scss').version('css/app.css').browserify('app.js');
 });
```

Then run following command which will create **rev-manifest.json** file in **public/build** directory.

```
 gulp --production
```

Good luck!!