# Laravel 5.2 Elixir

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I am using laravel 5.2 and I've successfully create all.css in `public/css` folder using gulp.

but when I try to use all.css in view admin.login using following line of code as defined in laravel 5.2 documentation and it not works

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ elixir('css/all.css') }}">
```

and when I use this following line of code it works.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('/public/' . elixir('css/all.css')) }}">
```

Is it correct? or I am missing some thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simple put all.css file into `public/css` location and you want to simply display this file, you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/all.css") }}>
```

However if you plan to modify this file and you don't want to have caching issues, you can put this all.css file again into

`public/css` then write below code into `gulpfile.js`

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version("public/css/all.css");
});
```

now you need to run gulp in your console

```
gulp
```

Now you can use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir("css/all.css") }}>
```

This original [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353295/laravel-5-css-file-is-not-defined-in-asset-manifest) will explain better :)

Comment: @OzanKurt: That's why I have included original author link also :)

Comment: You can link directly

Comment: Yes. But one of moderators told me that when you are reffering any link then also put useful content of that link. I have included both.

Comment: Please change something in your answer so that i can undo my vote then

Comment: I've rev-manifest.json file in build folder than why its not working with just '{{ elixir('css/all.css') }}' why I've to give full path '{{ url('/public/' . elixir('css/all.css')) }}'

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("css/all.css") }}">
You forgot a " at the end